# Started my project after about half a year and got version errors

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, version

Hi i started my android studio project after half a year and ofcourse i got a bunch of version errors. so i thought lets start migrating then and started to setup newer version within the buildgradle. But it does not matter what i do i have set a higher version on both Kotlin version and hilt version but i still get this error message

e: This version (1.4.3) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.8.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.8.21 which is not known to be compatible.  Please consult the Compose-Kotlin compatibility map located at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin to choose a compatible version pair (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

and before i get the answer change the kotlin version... i already did this. my project have a second module in it but what i can see i cant switch any kotlin version in that module...

Before all this i got an error that just said [Hilt]

Comment: Have you tried using version 1.4.7 of the Compose Compiler?